# Is it possible to make "image" or "snapshot", "service" of azure databricks solution?

Tags: azure, deployment, databricks, azure-databricks

I have an idea. Maybe it is really off. But... I would like to create an Azure DB solution, set it up, install required libraries, deploy a model, databases and so on. Once it is all tested, I would like to create something like my own service and redeploy it on customer's Azure portal. Is it possible? I understand, lots of thing need to be customized anyway, but we would like to have enviroment almost ready to go to use functional models.

If it is possible, how? It is possible to make this "azure databricks custom service" dployable on AWS?

If there is no way, to have almost ready to go enviroment, what would you suggets? Init scripts, download libraries, download github code, ...?

Comment: Actually, people from Microsfot told me, there is a some way through disaster recovery routine. Also it's possible to export whole workspace including data in it. I dit not tested yet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I think it's possible but pretty challenging.  I think you would need to leverage automation, the Databricks CLI, and other techniques.  It will be harder if you're switching between Azure and AWS.